# Supress aggregation until custom condition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka DSL. How would I proceed to suppress the output of an aggregation (similar behavior to [this](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Suppressed.html#untilWindowCloses-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed.StrictBufferConfig-)) with a custom condition?

Let's say for every key I may have a START and a STOP event. I only want to aggregate this key when the STOP event arrives or after a timeout.

The desired flow would be something roughly like this:

```
time    input-topic                     output-topic
1       key1:{type:start, time: 0}    ...
3       key2:{type:start, time: 2}    ...
4       key1:{type:stop, time:3}      ...
4+e     ...                           key1:{type:closed, duration:3}
61      ...                           ...
61+e    ...                           key2:{type:timeout, duration:60}
```

where the timeout is 60 units of time and *e* is a an arbitrary time the stream takes to process the event.

The code (pseudocode for now) would be something like

```
KStream<String,String> sourceStream = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(stringSerializer, stringSerializer));
KGroupedStream<String, String> groupedStream = sourceStream
        .groupByKey();

KTable<String, String> aggregatedStream = groupedStream
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(myCustomCondition()))
        .aggregate(
                () -> null,
                (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggregateStartStop(aggValue, newValue),
                Materialized
                        .<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("aggregated-stream-store")
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
        );
aggregatedStream.toStream();

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsSettings);

streams.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the KTable to store the state (in your case, the `type`) along with a 60 second window. Whenever you receive an event for that particular key you update the state and time. Then you can use a filter before a `.to()` method to either send or not send a message to the outgoing topic based on the state (`type`).

Take a look at Neil Avery's blog post here:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/journey-to-event-driven-part-4-four-pillars-of-event-streaming-microservices
And scroll down to Event Flow Breakdown 1. Payments inflight
It's where I got the idea from.